# how to use hilt test in android multi module?

Tags: android, testing, dagger-hilt, multi-module

```
//data module
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [UseCaseModule::class]
)
abstract class TestUseCaseModule {

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract fun bindsSaveDataUseCase(saveDataUseCaseImpl: SaveDataUseCaseImpl): SaveDataUseCase

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract fun bindsLoadDataUseCase(loadDataUseCaseImpl: LoadDataUseCaseImpl): LoadDataUseCase
}


//domain module

class LoadDataUseCaseImpl @Inject constructor(private val repository: TestRepository):
    LoadDataUseCase {
    override fun invoke(): Flow<List<TestModel>> = repository.load()
}
```

Dependency injection in the repository is not possible in the use case in the domain module.
A missing binding error occurs.
clearly
I created a singleton in the data module.
I don't know why it doesn't work.